# How to change Flutter widget Visibility using Firestore Database in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, icons

Good afternoon, I am developing my application and I want to implement a blue tick visualization system using FireStore database,

here is a screenshot of the user's document:

[image: here is a screenshot of the user's document]

here is the whole code

```
class ProfileMainWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserEntity currentUser;

  const ProfileMainWidget({Key? key, required this.currentUser}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProfileMainWidget> createState() => _ProfileMainWidgetState();
}

class _ProfileMainWidgetState extends State<ProfileMainWidget> {
  bool isVerify = true;
  @override
  void initState() {

    BlocProvider.of<PostCubit>(context).getPosts(post: PostEntity());
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DynamicColorBuilder(
        builder: (lightColorScheme, darkColorScheme,) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title:

          Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
          Text(
             '${widget.currentUser.username}', style: TextStyle( fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25, ),
           ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: (isVerify) ? false : true,
                    child: Icon(Icons.verified_sharp, color: Colors.blue,size: 17,),
                  ),
              ]
          ),
```

I need to hide or show a widget icon from a value in a firestore document, if anyone can help I would really appreciate it, hope my question helps someone.

I've looked all over the internet and haven't found anything, I've tried to figure it out myself, but nothing helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are getting UserEntity passed from previous page. Then you should be using the "widget.currentUser.verification" for Visibility.

```
visible: widget.currentUser.verification,
```

Not the isVerify bool because it's already set to true and you're using it wrong in visibility parameter.

Comment: thank you very much, I spent 2 hours, figured it out and everything works fine, it's just that my project is not small and I'm constantly confused, but what I wanted, it turned out thanks again

Answer (score 2):

The expression tests the value of the boolean variable isVerify. If isVerify is true, then the expression evaluates to false. Otherwise, it evaluates to true.

As mentioned above, you are trying to hide the blue mark when its true or the user is verified and show it when the user is not verified or false.

if you are trying to show the blue mark when the user is verified, you need to change the 'false and true' positions like:

visible: (isVerify) ? true: false,

this is all i knew about the problem and i hope this was your answer

best wishes...